# Using Python to execute a DB2 SQL script and export results to a csv file, but not getting the result expected. How do I fix this?

Tags: python, db2, export-to-csv

I'm using a python script to access a DB2 database and export the fetched data to a csv file using pandas. The DB2 SQL script executes just fine in DBeaver and I get the expected result of 34,000 rows of data but when I execute the exact same script via python it only returns 10,800 rows of data.

I've asked ChatGPT for various different variations of the python script but no matter how many different ways I write it I still get only 10,800 rows.

Has anyone come across this problem before?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

I've tried this script (And many others) but I always get the same result of 10,800 rows when I should get 34,000 rows

Python version: base 3.7.6 (Conda)
DB2 version: DB2 v11.1.0.1527
Driver: Db2 for LUW
ibm_db package version 3.0.2 (This is most recent package available in my org)

```
from ibm_db import connect
import pandas as pd
import ibm_db_dbi
import pandas as pd
import csv

DBdetails = connect('DATABASE=;'
                    'HOSTNAME=;'
                    'PORT=;'
                    'PROTOCOL=;'
                    'UID=;'
                    'PWD=;', '', '')
conn = ibm_db_dbi.Connection(DBdetails)

# Execute the SQL script
with open("DB2SQLquery.sql", "r") as script_file:
    sql_script = script_file.read()
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql_script)

# Fetch and export the result set in batches of 5,000 rows
fetch_size = 5000
with open("output.csv", "w", newline="") as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow([i[0] for i in cursor.description])
    while True:
        rows = cursor.fetchmany(fetch_size)
        if not rows:
            break
        writer.writerows(rows)

# Close the database connection
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

SQL Script that it executes:

```
SELECT  USERTYPE,TYPENAME 
FROM     mytable t 
WHERE   VALID = 'V'
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show what's in the SQL script, and specify exactly your __versions__ of software packages (python, dbi,  odbc driver name and version ), along with your operating-system.

Comment: Please add the content of your SQL script (redact anything confidential).  Otherwise your question may get closed for lack of detail. Also, you will need to check the outcome of using the __current__ build of `ibm_db` (which is 3.1.4 at today's date, as your edit says you are using the older 3.0.2 build).

Comment: Symptom is not reproducible with ibm_db 3.1.4, your code runs correctly in my context, with over 350000 rows. Some local problem at your site. You need to do some debugging, run a trace. check other databases, other test environments etc.   This is not a problem for stackoverflow, as we cannot "guess" what is happening, you have to tell us!